# Identical host file entry works in Windows 7 but not in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-7, windows-8.1, hosts-file

If I add an entry to a Windows 7 hosts file then it works. If I add the same entry to a windows 8.1 hosts file then it doesn't work. It is for a web site and this is the only way to have access to it. Other colleagues in the workplace with win 8.1 machines have the same problem. I have done this several times before with different IP addresses and never had this problem before.

Comment: Is the same application reading the host file?

Comment: It's for a web site, so yes, i've tried on the win 7 machine with chrome and on mine (win 8.1) with both ie, chrome.

Comment: Try restarting the DNS client, and flushing the DNS using ipconfig. The ping the website and see if it pings the IP you set in hosts.

Comment: Some great tips here.. [windows - hosts file ignored, how to troubleshoot?](http://serverfault.com/questions/452268/hosts-file-ignored-how-to-troubleshoot)